# Perturbation theory for optical lattice

Tags: perturbation-theory, bose-einstein-condensate, optical-lattices

This afternoon, I wondered about the following problem, but I cannot find the continuation. Can you help me ?

We consider the following unperturbed 1D optical lattice Hamiltonian

$$\hat{H}_0=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+V_0 \cos(2k_Lx)$$

According to the Bloch theorem, the energy eingenstates of $\hat{H}_0$ can be written

$$\phi_{n,q}(x)=e^{iqx}u_{n,q}(x)$$
where the $u_{n,q}$'s are periodic functions of space with period d (period of the lattice).Their Fourier expansion is given by
$$u_{n,q(x)}=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\tilde{u}_{n,q}(m)e^{iQ_mx}$$
where $Q_m=2mk_L$

We consider now a perturbative lattice with much longer spatial periodicity ($\alpha ,k\ll 
 1$)

$$\hat{H}_1=\alpha V_0 \cos(2kk_Lx)$$

**We are interested in how this perturbation affects the ground state of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $\phi_{0,0}(x)$.**
First order perturbation theory tell us that this state is affected in the following manner:

$$
|\phi_{0,0}\rangle = |\phi_{0,0} \rangle + \alpha\sum_{(n,q) \neq (0,0)} |\phi_{n,q}\rangle \frac{\langle \phi_{n,q}|H_1|\phi_{0,0}\rangle}{E_0-E_{n,q}} 
$$

We need to compute the matrix element
$$C=\langle \phi_{n,q}|H_1|\phi_{0,0}\rangle$$

$$C=\alpha V_0 \int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{iqx}u_{n,q}(x)\cos(2kk_Lx)u_{0,0}(x)$$

$$C=\alpha V_0 \int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{iqx}\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}\tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)e^{-i Q_m x}\cos(2k k_L x)\sum_{p \in \mathbb{Z}}u_{0,0}(p) e^{ i Q_p x} $$

$$C=\alpha V_0\sum_{m,p\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)  \tilde{u}_{0,0} (p) \int_{-\infty }^\infty   e^{i(q-Q_m+Q_p)x}\cos(2kk_Lx)$$

$$C=\frac{\alpha V_0}{2}\sum_{m,p\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)  \tilde{u}_{0,0} (p) \int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{i(q-Q_m+Q_p+2kk_L)x}+e^{i(q-Q_m+Q_p-2kk_L)x}$$

$$C=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m,p\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)  \tilde{u}_{0,0} (p) \left[\delta_{(q-Q_m+Q_p+2kk_L)} +\delta_{(q-Q_m+Q_p-2kk_L)}\right]$$

$$C=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m,p\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)  \tilde{u}_{0,0} (p) \left[\delta_{(q+2(p+k-m)k_L)} +\delta_{(q+2(p-k-m)k_L)}\right]=C_1+C_2$$

rewriting $q\equiv 2q k_L$
$$C_1=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m,p\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)  \tilde{u}_{0,0} (p) \left[\delta_{(2(q+p+k-m)k_L)}\right]$$

$$C_1=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)  \tilde{u}_{0,0} (m-q-k) $$

while

$$C_2=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m)  \tilde{u}_{0,0} (m-q+k) $$

Here I do not know what to do, because I do not know the expression of the  $\tilde{u}$'s, so I consider that they are smooth functions of their argument so that

$$C_1=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m) \left[ \tilde{u}_{0,0} (m-q) -k\tilde{u}_{0,0}' (m-q) +\frac{k^2}{2}\tilde{u}_{0,0}'' (m-q)\right] $$

$$C_2=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m) \left[ \tilde{u}_{0,0} (m-q) +k\tilde{u}_{0,0}' (m-q) +\frac{k^2}{2}\tilde{u}_{0,0}'' (m-q)\right] $$

$$C=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m) \left[ \tilde{u}_{0,0} (m-q)  +k^2\tilde{u}_{0,0}'' (m-q)\right] $$

$$C=\pi \alpha V_0\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m) \left[ \tilde{u}_{0,0} (m-q) \right]... $$

$$...+ k^2 \pi \alpha V_0 \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} \tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m) \left[ \tilde{u}_{0,0}'' (m-q) \right]=\overline{C}(q)+k^2\overline{C}''(q)$$

Reinjecting in the perturbative sum, we end up with
$$
|\phi_{0,0}\rangle = |\phi_{0,0} \rangle + \alpha\sum_{(n,q) \neq (0,0)} |\phi_{n,q}\rangle \frac{\overline{C}(q)+k^2\overline{C}''(q)}{E_0-E_{n,q}} 
$$

Now if  $k=0$, there is no pertubation, and therefore the term involving $\overline{C}$ must be null, so we end up with

$$
|\phi_{0,0}\rangle = |\phi_{0,0} \rangle + \alpha k^2\sum_{(n,q) \neq (0,0)} |\phi_{n,q}\rangle \frac{\overline{C}''(q)}{E_0-E_{n,q}} 
$$

$$
|\phi_{0,0}\rangle = |\phi_{0,0} \rangle +\pi \alpha^2 V_0 k^2\sum_{(n,q) \neq (0,0)} \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} |\phi_{n,q}\rangle \frac{\tilde{u}_{n,q}^*(m) \left[ \tilde{u}_{0,0}'' (m-q) \right]}{E_0-E_{n,q}} 
$$
**Questions:** 
I am interested in any comment on the derivation, if something is wrong for example.
I am interested in any possible continuation you can come up with.
I am interested in any alternative solution to the problem.
I am interested in any physical interpretation of the formulae, in particular what would I see if I were to suddenly release a condensate trapped in such an optical lattice after time of flight ?

I will continue to update the derivation if I have any new idea.

Edit: my derivation is not coherent, I use both discrete and continuous representations.